# java parsing file with variable length

Tags: java

I have textfiles with many lines like this:

```
12444423100000123       123456 5147894269       123456        TEST PR/123/12/11/1/01 D222

12534223100000123       765432 5147124269       124541        PR/123/12/11/1/01      D111
```

I need to parse each line and create a new file. These seperate characters are not the final version. This means that I also need to split some of them that are not splitted with white space and save in different variables like:

```
12444423100000123 in 1244442  3100000123       
String number1=1244442;
String number2=3100000123
```

Therefore I need to make sure to remove the white space before parsing:

```
String line = lines[0];
line = removeSpaces(line); 

public static String removeSpaces (String arg)
{
    Pattern whitespace = Pattern.compile("\\s");
    Matcher matcher = whitespace.matcher(arg);
    String result = "";
    if (matcher.find()) {
        result = matcher.replaceAll("");
    }
    return result;
}
```

After you remove the whitespaces the line looks like this:

```
124444231000001231234565147894269123456TESTPR/123/12/11/1/01D222
```

I have definite lengths for each column, so I know how long each number is
therefore it is easy with the substring function, for example:

```
String number1= line.substring(0, 19);
String number2= line.substring(20, 26);
.......
```

However, the length of these numbers (which are marked with **) are not fixed
( i dont know how long this number can be):

```
12444423100000123       123456 5147894269       123456        **TEST PR/123/12/11/1/01** D222

12534223100000123       765432 5147124269       124541         **PR/123/12/11/1/01** D111
```

However the last five last characters, which also need to be stored in a seperate column are always fixed (like D222, D111).

I dont know how to parse these numbers (PR/123/12/11/1/01 or TEST PR/123/12/11/1/01) in a sepeate column, since I dont know how long they are...

EDIT:
Each column is not seperated by whitespace...some columns are for example like this : 111111111222222   222233....Here I need to save 111111111, 222222 and 222233 in seperate variables, therefore I cannot use the whitespace as a seperator

Comment: Can you show us what the expected output looks like?

Comment: What is your problem? Not able to store or not able to parse? At first sight it seems much more easier to read lines verbatim and then extract the corresponding fields?

Comment: Why not change your regex to find 1 or more spaces and replace that find with a delimiter mayber say a comma.  Then you could just `String::split` at the commas and you would have a `String[]` where each index was a different column

Comment: Why do yo delete whitespaces? Stop doing it and change your indexes accordingly. Remove whitespaces after parsing.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear what you are asking because you never showed us what the final columns should be.

Comment: Sry, edited my question. I hope it is clearer know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some regex, here i've printed the different groups you want you lay use them another way

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String str1 = "12444423100000123       123456 5147894269       123456        TEST PR/123/12/11/1/01 D222";
   String str2 = "12534223100000123       765432 5147124269       124541        PR/123/12/11/1/01      D111";

   String patt = "(\\d{17})\\s+(\\d{6})\\s+(\\d{10})\\s+(\\d{6})\\s+((\\s|\\w)*\\/((\\d{1,3}\\/?)*\\d{1,3}))\\s+(\\w\\d{3})"
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(patt);

   for (String s : Arrays.asList(str1, str2) {
      Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
      if (m.find()) {                       // for str1               // str2
         System.out.println(m.group(1));   // 12444423100000123       // 12534223100000123
         System.out.println(m.group(2));   // 123456                  // 765432
         System.out.println(m.group(3));   // 5147894269              // 5147124269
         System.out.println(m.group(4));   // 123456                  // 124541
         System.out.println(m.group(5));   // TEST PR/123/12/11/1/01  // PR/123/12/11/1/01
         System.out.println(m.group(9));   // D222                    // D111
      }
      System.out.println();
  }
}
```

The pattern is only composed of `capturing groups`, `digit groups` and `spaces`

> [**`Online Example`**](https://regex101.com/r/J8b7u4/3)

Comment: thx, i am not familiar with regex but I am seeing that your pattern conatins words like "Test" or "PR" ..however there are many lines and I dont know if this column starts with "Test" or "Pr" and so on..

Comment: smart regexp, but hard to understand and maintain.

Comment: @Norbert94 I've changed, you can have any word, with or without space, and at the end D.. can be another letter, check the example I've update

Comment: @BartoszBilicki understand because long ^^ because of user question, it's only group of digit and space and once some letters

Comment: true. it is long but simple regexp. as you said just groups of digits and letters. If input format is fixed then this solution is fine. otherwise, if you need to deduce how to parse field N+1 based on value of field N (previous field) then I believe imperative approach (ifs, split, substring) is easier to reason about and evolve.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at sample data, problematic strings

```
PR/123/12/11/1/01
PR/123/12/11/1/01
```

always have 5 slashes (/). And last token is always 2 chars long. just split this string using / as splitting characters.

For parsing rest of the string, removing whitespaces is not good idea. It would be simpler to replace all consecutive whitespaces with single whitespace, then split using whitespace as separator.

After tokenizing by whitespace you will see that column with TEST world has more tokens that one without TEST world. You may choose parsing logic based on number  of tokens (and value of some tokens, if you want to).

Comment: Each column is not seperated by whitespace...some columns are for example like this : 111111111222222   222233....Here I need to save 111111111, 222222 and 222233 in seperate variables, therefore I cannot use the whitespace as a seperator

Comment: In that case you may first separate by whitespace anyway, and then use substring to work with first column.

Comment: I think you solution may be a good idea. I just replace the whitespaces with a single space and work with the substring. However not only the first columnd but also other colums need to be splitted which are not seperated with whitespace

Comment: thats fine, you could work with substring any token, not just first one.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not the columns can contain whitespaces, you should split the files on the whitespaces. Then you can handle any length column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String s1 = "12444423100000123       123456 5147894269       123456        TEST PR/123/12/11/1/01 D222";
s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\s+", "_");
System.out.println(s1);
s1 = "12534223100000123       765432 5147124269       124541        PR/123/12/11/1/01      D111";
s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\s+", "_");
System.out.println(s1);
```

So once you split that result string then I think manipulation becomes more easy.